# Remove objects from array that match a test against a property

Tags: jq

I'd like to remove from an array objects that pass a test against a property'

Assume we have the following array:

```
[
  {
     "path": "a/b/v1-another"
  },
  {
     "path": "a/b/v1"
  }
]
```

I'd like to remove from the array the object that match the test `a/b/*` against `path` property

Comment: What does "a/b/*" mean?  Does it match "a/b//c"?  "a/b/"? "a/b/c/d"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
jq '.[]|select(.path|startswith("a/b/")|not)' file.json
```

Comment: S*** function select from right in front of my eyes but I haven't seen it. Thank you